# Google analytics click event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to set up click tracking on a link on an acquisition page. I have added the following code just below my google analytics JS snippet:

```
 jQuery(".submit-button").click(function(){

  ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'register',
  eventAction: 'click',
  eventLabel: 'registrations'
});
 });
```

First question is do I need to add a value to the object above or will the default value be 1?

Secondly to see the click reporting in google anayltics I have set up a Goal in the admin panel that has the following settings:

Goal setup: custom

Goal Description: Event

Goal Details: 
    Category - Equals to - register,
    Action - Equals to - click,
    Label - Equals to - registrations,
    Value - Equals to - **(this field is set to blank)**

Second question: is this the correct way to intercept my click event in the GA interface?

Sorry if this is an obvious question but online documentation isn't 100% clear with click events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code is correct (provided the ga code has been loaded before and a tracker with the default name has been created). Goal setup looks okay, too.

No, value will not default to one, it will default to zero - which is probably  want you want anyway, because the event value is a metric (number) that is used to monetize goals that are not transactions. If you set a value it would for example be used in the Adwords reports when calculating the ROAS (return on advertising spend). Typically you would put a number there that reflects how much value you assign to a goal conversion, and that value will mpst of the time not be "1" (unless 1 Dollar/Euro/etc is your expected revenue from a goal conversion). If you do not assign a monetary value to the goal conversion just skip it, it's optional (so your setup is fine).